# Read contents of excel file from Stream

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a file stream which is created from an excel file. I need to read the contents of this stream and get the excel sheets from it. Any ideas how can I do this?

Note: I have to do this without using any third party libraries

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://servername:1056/ExcelFiles/Myfile.xlsx", UriKind.Absolute));
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream fs = response.GetResponseStream() as Stream;
```

Here I need to read the contents of fs without having to saving the file to local system/disk

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
WebClient webClient= new WebClient();
Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead("http://servername:1056/ExcelFiles/Myfile.xlsx");
  //StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
  //String content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
// Read the Document using SpreadSheetDocument Method 
var ssDoc = SpreadSheetDocument.Open(stream, false);
```

[SpreadsheetDocument.Open method (Stream, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc562185)

Comment: Content gives the output like this ..how to get data from contents without having to save to a file?0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\f��H�C���n ���]&��*`����Q�A��$�F��Cx{�օ\fCS7\"�U���2��'[�A��%��*�Ț�\"o���y���;:�\tG�l�Q\a�,ZOU�=c��\\g���H��.�����R3��4g.�Z��|,���\"w�ȩ���m�Q�gC�Z�Jq{�\at�Cy-�ͽ��J�@q�]xz�\ta���ag,�2��5��\b�TN�*��'T�l[?�[ӭ�댓��q���b�S9����RS��Ųm\b�����m#G�Rs-�A\\��R�|j^m*��x��;'�5��/\\a4�=�ې`6)��R����p�u�:.\b��u��b-{2� ���JXD��x&��

Answer (score 0):

you can use SpreadSheetDocument for reading the data from the stream which has a Static method

```
var doc = SpreadSheetDocument.Open(docName, true);
```

More on this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478410

Reading as memmorystream

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

byte[] fileArray = wc.DownloadData("url is inserted here");

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileArray);
```

Comment: Note that I should not be using any other third party libraries or SDK. Any other way?